# How can I create a group of modules in Android Studio like Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have opened the open source project [small](https://github.com/wequick/Small/blob/master/Android/Sample/README.md) in my AS, and I found some projects with same prefix were organized together, as shown below. And I found the meaning of the "app" icon is "group of module" from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html. What's more, the settings.gradle does not has any magic operation at all, the projects just in a flattern directory. How are the group created?

Sorry about the "small" project is in Chinese, just clone all project and import a module by choosing the DevSample, if you wanna a try.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there, have you figured out how the groups are generated?  I am also very interested in it, since this can make my modules well organized!

Comment: Sorry , not yet, hope some knew it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a parent project, i.e. 'lib', and the child project (style for example) path should be
'lib:style:'.

Answer (score 0):

The Intellij [official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#group-by-qualified-names) also have an explanation on how to do this. However, I was not able to replicate in Android Studio. I believe this is because Android Studio is based on the community edition (free version) of Intellij and they do not allow for the module grouping feature.